# Como soluciono este error de mi gradle con la librería apache?

Tags: java, android, gradle

Estoy tratando de abrir mi proyecto de android en Android Studio y al abrirlo me marca el error en la librería

> **Unable to find optional library: org.apache.http.legacy**

no entiendo por que...

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.user.activofijo"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
android {
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
dependencies {
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
      compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
      compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
      compile 'com.baoyz.swipemenulistview:library:1.3.0'
      compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
      compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.5.0'
      compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
      compile 'com.mobsandgeeks:android-saripaar:2.0.2'
      compile 'com.mobsandgeeks:android-saripaar:2.0.3'
      compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0'
      compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
      compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+'
}
```

[image: Error httplegacy]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debido a que usas un `compileSdkVersion 23` deberías dejar de usar las librerías apache para conexión y usar **[HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)**.

Para resolver tu problema,

> warning unable to find optional library org.apache.http.legacy

agrega el `.jar` directamente al folder `/libs`.

```
android {
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    }
```

El .jar lo puedes descargar de **[Apache Software Foundation](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi)**

#### *Te recomiendo cambiar a **[HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)**

Answer (score 0):

agrega estas lineas a tu archivo gradle

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

en el SDK manager actualiza el  Android SDK tools rev 24.4.1 y SDK platform tools a la version 23.1. Luego reinicia android studio.

yo uso esta version de la libreria

```
compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
```