# Enviar imagen al servidor con MultipartEntityBuilder y HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, android, http

Estoy tratando de enviar una imagen al servidor utilizando HttpUrlConnection y MultipartEntityBuilder. El problema es que cuando ejecuto la función background, para enviarla y obtener como respuesta un String que diga por parte del servidor que ha sido enviada con éxito, la aplicación crashea. El código es el siguiente:

```
public class EnvioImagenes extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    public String direccion="";
    public EnvioImagenes(String cuerpo){
        direccion=cuerpo;
    }


    protected String doInBackground(String... url){
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
        ContentBody contentPart = new ByteArrayBody(bos.toByteArray(), direccion);
        MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        multipartEntity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        multipartEntity.addPart("Picture",contentPart);

        try {
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url[0]).openConnection();
            connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            //Si quiero enviar/recibir una respuesta en el cuerpo del mensaje, tiene que estar lo siguiente:
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            String boundary= "--------------"+System.currentTimeMillis();
            multipartEntity.setBoundary(boundary);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            DataOutputStream dos=new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            //connection.addRequestProperty(multipartEntity.getClass().getName(), multipartEntity.getClass().toString());
            //OutputStream output=new BufferedOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            dos.writeBytes("\r\n");
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
            //output.write(body.getBytes());
            //output.flush();

            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line;
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }

            String responseString = result.toString();
            inputStream.close();
            connection.disconnect();
            return responseString;

        } catch(Exception exc) {
            String error = exc.toString();
            Log.e("Este es el error-----", exc.getMessage());
            return error;
        }
    }
}
```

AVISO: para poder utilizar MultipartEntityBuilder tuve que bajar una librería de apache (haciendo lo que dice esta pregunta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28470486/android-multipartentity-and-dependencies), la cual me tira la siguiente advertencia cuando la quiero utilizar (aunque como no uso HttpClient no creo que influya eso):

```
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.3 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
```

Este es el Build.gradle de la app:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.franco.pruebalogin"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.3'
}
```

Comment: Y cual es el mensaje desplegado en el LogCat al marcar el error???

Comment: Es que el problema es ese: el logcat no me marca ningun error con eso que escribi. Directamente dice que hay un `FATAL EXCEPTION` y cierra la app. Por eso sospecho que el problema puede ser el warning que me aparece con la libreria bajada

Comment: ok posiblemente, podrias agregar tu build.gradle, donde se agregan las dependencias?

Comment: dices de agregar la dependencia que me tira esa advertencia? sisi, la puedo agregar y sacar constantemente sin problema alguno. el problema esta en que aparece el warning que mostre antes...pero como poder se puede. Lo unico que cuando presiono Sync now, antes de aparecer el otro warning, me muestra esto: Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.3 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.

Comment: me refiero a que agregues tu build.gradle para revisar la configuración.

Comment: ahi lo agregue @Jorgesys

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53707/discussion-between-jorgesys-and-f-riggio).

Answer (score 1):

> Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.3
>   is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal
>   version provided by Android.
>            In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages

Si usas las librerías de apache debes agregar la configuración para el soporte de las mismas ya que en realidad son obsoletas:

```
android {
    ...
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    ...
    ...
}
```

El .jar debe estar dentro del folder /libs, para descargarlo ve esta respuesta:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/6848/95

Comment: hay algun problema con usarlas al ser obsoletas...?? En realidad la use como plan inicial como para poder enviar la imagen usando  MultipartEntityBuilder y HttpUrlConnection ya que habia usado antes esto ultimo....De ultima uso un plan B pero como ya estaba mas o menos familiarizado con eso preferi conservarlo

Comment: Ahi agregue como creo que me habias dicho la libreria...Aunque me sigue apareciendo el mismo warning

Comment: Por el momento no hay problema pero en algún la configuración de tu proyecto te obligaría a cambiar a Httpurlconnection, por cierto agregaste el .jar  al folder /libs.?

Comment: Revisa el chat que ahi te mostre lo que hice....Pero por que me harias cambiarlo? Lo use anteriormente para enviar cadenas de texto y me anduvo sin problema. Me dirias de cambiarlo por algo que cambie demasiado mi codigo? Porque preferiria que no....Aviso que investigue que HttpClient esta descontinuado desde android M. Lo digo por si querias que lo use. Tambien una que me dijeron fue usar OkHttp o algo asi pero creo que eso seria completamente distinto ya...